# set default element to display onload - mootools

Tags: javascript, mootools, element

I found this code via http://mrpaolo.github.io/mootools30days/20.html

```
var showFunction = function() {
   $$('.hidden').setStyle('display', 'none'); 
   this.setStyle('display', 'block');
}


window.addEvent('domready', function() {
   var elOneB = $('contentoneB');
   var elTwoB = $('contenttwoB');
   var elThreeB = $('contentthreeB');

   $('oneB').addEvent('click', showFunction.bind(elOneB));
   $('twoB').addEvent('click', showFunction.bind(elTwoB));
   $('threeB').addEvent('click', showFunction.bind(elThreeB));
});
```

I would like to make one of the elements display onload by default. Is this doable?

Answer (score 2):

that code is pretty rigid. a lot of these tutorials are pretty bad / out of date / out of touch with best practices.

anyway, you should convert to something that is less DRY. to get it working as is, you can do:

```
$('twoB').fireEvent('click');
```

but you really should refactor to something that is not coupled to ids and hard implicit bindings or inline CSS styles etc.

```
(function(){
    var contentDivs = document.getElements('div.content');
    document.getElements('button.button-control').addEvent('click', function(e){
        contentDivs.addClass('hide');
        document.getElement('div.content.' + this.get('data-content')).removeClass('hide');
    });

}());

// pick one to show
document.getElement('button').fireEvent('click');
```

this with a dom of:

```
<button class="button-control" data-content="content-one">one</button>
<button class="button-control" data-content="content-two">two</button>
<button class="button-control" data-content="content-three">three</button>

<div class="content hide content-one">
    one
</div>
<div class="content hide content-two">
    two
</div>
<div class="content hide content-three">
    three
</div>
```

and CSS of

```
.hide { 
    display: none; 
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dimitar/a7K4c/ - it will allow you to easily add more items via simply modifying the markup w/o touching your code.

Comment: Thanks both! I've tried your above code on this page in the right column but cant seem to figure out what I am doing wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: I really like your code above, its very elegant and simple however I cant seem to figure out why it wont remove the .hide class on this page http://www.landnsand.co.za/dev/test/news in the right column. I implemented it exaclty as in your fiddle but must be missing something.

Comment: you have only done the markup but the js code is not there. if you just paste the code in the console and then click the buttons, it works.

Comment: Thanks again Dimitar! I took another look and it appears I am loading the js file TabPane.js when the page loads.

Comment: Using firebug I get this error - 

        TypeError: document.getElement(...) is null
        document.getElement('button').fireEvent('click');

What I read about it is that the element seeked by getElement isnt being found correct? Could that be the problem?

Comment: Ive checked about 10 times and to me it seems the script is being loaded (TabPane.js) as I can view it via the source code but still no joy though. Any suggestions?

Comment: I even tried to disable to other scripts to see if they were conflicting but no luck yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below line of code

```
  <body onLoad="setInterval('var elOneB = $('contentoneB');',1000)">
```

After "<"head">" section.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the input - I found this thread and it seems to solve the problem.
It was to do with the positioning of the script on the page
http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=727&t=803161

Comment: your link is broken... maybe a page that needs login?